# Firebase JS Function Appears to add leading whitespace to variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

First post and the stupidity of it makes me shudder.

Working on a play around messenger app in android using Firebase. I have a Firebase function that I'm trying to work through to send a notification to receiver. Problem is encountered trying to specify database ref.

```
sendNewMessageNotification

Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/Users/${senderUid}". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at validatePathString (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1667:15)
    at validateRootPathString (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1679:5)
    at Reference.child (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13843:17)
    at Database.ref (/srv/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15097:48)
    at exports.sendNewMessageNotification.functions.database.ref.onCreate (/srv/index.js:24:41)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

I'm logging the incoming message as (ln 13):

```
{ blockedByReceiver: false,
  concatUserIds: '1CclNhoTiOamWThUTRSQVtNhNpk2Pnwb1pLAh0d1nxpgfdU1HUsYaIA3',
  isimage: false,
  isseen: false,
  message: '66',
  receiver: '1CclNhoTiOamWThUTRSQVtNhNpk2',
  sender: 'Pnwb1pLAh0d1nxpgfdU1HUsYaIA3',
  timesent: 1588645656253,
  uid: '-M6XeEOUbGjAU5ut7lQw',
  url: '' }
```

But when I log what the attributes translate to I see that there is a leading whitespace (ln 17):

```
sender: Pnwb1pLAh0d1nxpgfdU1HUsYaIA3  receiver: 1CclNhoTiOamWThUTRSQVtNhNpk2  resulting path: /Users/ Pnwb1pLAh0d1nxpgfdU1HUsYaIA3
```

Full Code from function:

```
exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/Chats/{newChat}')
    .onCreate(async (change, context) => {
        console.log(change.val());
        const message=change.val();
        const senderUid=message.sender.trim();
        const receiverUid=message.receiver.trim();
        console.log('sender:', message.sender, ' receiver:', message.receiver, ' resulting path: /Users/', senderUid);
        const sender = admin.database().ref('/Users/${senderUid}').once('value');
        const receiver = admin.database().ref('/Users/${receiverUid}').once('value');
        const blockList = admin.database.ref('/BlockList').orderByChild( "blockerUid").equalTo(receiverUid).once('value');

        const results = await Promise.all([sender, receiver, blockList]);
        senderSnapshot = results[0];
        receiverSnapshot = results[1];
        blockerSnapshot = results[2];

        blockerSnapshot.forEach( result => {
            if (result.blockeeUid == sender.id) {
                console.log("message ${message.id} from ${sender.id} blocked by ${receiver.id}");
                return snapshot.ref.child("blockedByReceiver").set(true);
            }
        } );

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: 'You have a new message!',
                body: '${sender.username} has send you a message.',
                icon: iconUrl
            }
        }
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(receiver.token, payload)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("New Message notification for message ${message.id} sent successfully to user ${message.receiver}");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error encountered sending new message notification for message ${message.id} sent successfully to user ${message.receiver}, error:", error);
            });
    });
```

I've tried a couple of different things and have looked around all night to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your expecting the value of a variable to be inserted into a string:

```
'/Users/${senderUid}'
```

That's not possible with single quotes.  You'll need to use backtick quotes for that:

```
`/Users/${senderUid}`
```

You should make this change to all of the strings that are expecting variable interpolations (at least 4 by my count).

Comment: Looks like I was right about it being a stupid issue. Thanks Doug for your answer, solved the problem immediately. Cheers!